# Dropdown menu to view my sql database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown menu that displays the rows in my database. I want to create a button to take me to the row that I have selected in the dropdown menu. I am struggling trying to figure out how to add a button that can take me to the row that i have selected. Should I use an onClick button, javascript or is there another way I can do it. This is the code that populates my dropdown menu.

```
$sql = "SELECT classname FROM classroom";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='sub1'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<option value='" . $row['classname'] ."'>" .$row['classname'] . "</option>";

}

echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You can use `.onchange` if you are talking about HTML/JQuery. Where are these rows where you want to go(i guess scroll to).

Comment: I am actually trying to use php. Sorry i should have said that. I

Comment: Ok so you have echo out the drop down menu filled with rows from database. So when you select any of the option, what you want then?

Comment: I made a php page that shows all the information for a math class. The page is called viewclass.php?classname=math2072. The drop-down menu shows math2072 and I want the button to take me to viewclass.php?classname=math2072 when I select the name in the drop down menu and hit submit.

Comment: Look at this demo i created, Consider the `Drop-Down menu` and Table rows are created from Database. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/knt0cnqs/1/). Try selecting any option.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it gave me an idea of what to do for another project. I ended up using javascript.